# Size Classes and dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint, uitraitcollection

I am trying to calculate height of UITableViewCells. I have this working creating a prototype cell instance from a dynamic prototype configured in the storyboard by calling -dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: on the UITableView and then calling -systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: on the cell prototype. The problem is that the traitCollection and the constraints configured in the storyboard for the cell are always what I have set for Any:Any and the frame of the cell is always 320pt wide. This seems wrong. Is there something I'm missing? Is there some other way I should be laying out the cells to use size classes and instantiating them? Cells created using -dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: have the correct traitCollection and constraint values, but I obviously can't use that to create a "prototype" cell to calculate cell height as it triggers a call to -tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:.

Comment: @Lizza I haven't found a great solution. I worked around it for now it by getting [[UIScreen mainScreen] traitCollection] and setting the constraint values manually in the prototype cells based on that in code.